# Probability distribution exercise

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm never certain about my solutions on probability problems (applied), analytic probability and measure is good. I want to work as a TA on a engineering course, so i'm preparing myself doing problems. I'm having a bad time on this exercise, i don't know how to attack it. I would really appreciate your help.

An test software engineer at Adobe has proved that the probability that a program has fails is about 0.05. Actually, the test process is divided into two phases.

Phase 1: There is a random sample of 50 programs. If there are 2 bad programs, the lot is accepted. If there are at least 6, the lot is rejected, otherwise goto Phase 2

Phase 2:It's taken a second random sample of 100 software pieces. If the number of bad programs in this phase plus the number of bad programs in the first phase is not bigger than 6, the lot is accepted, otherwise it is rejected.

a) What is the probability that to a lot to be accepted in the first phase
b) If a lot of programs has to be tested by phase 2, what is the probability of been accepted

I would appreciate your help on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variable representing program failure is Bernoulli, as it only has two states: Pass and Fail. The sum of a sequence of Bernoulli's is binomially distributed, so we will be dealing with that family.

Now we have three possible states:

1. Batch has no more than two failures - ACCEPT
2. Batch has between three and five failures - Go to Phase II
3. Batch has six or more failures - REJECT

The probability that out of a batch of 50, no more than two fail, is P(0) + P(1) + P(2). The probability of getting to Phase II is $P(3) + P(4) + P(5)$. The probability of rejection is the rest, or $1 - P(X \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\})$. So as $p = 0.05$ we get:
$$
\begin{align}
P(0) = {50 \choose 0}0.05^0 0.95^{50} &\approx 0.076945\\
P(1) = {50 \choose 1}0.05^1 0.95^{49} &\approx 0.202487\\
P(2) = {50 \choose 2}0.05^2 0.95^{48} &\approx 0.261101\\
P(0) + P(1) + P(2) &\approx \mathbf{0.540533}\\
P(3) = {50 \choose 3}0.05^3 0.95^{47} &\approx 0.219875\\
P(4) = {50 \choose 4}0.05^4 0.95^{46} &\approx 0.135975\\
P(5) = {50 \choose 5}0.05^5 0.95^{45} &\approx 0.065841\\
P(3) + P(4) + P(5) &\approx \mathbf{0.421691}\\
P(\geq 6) = 1-P([0,\ldots,5]) \approx 1 - 0.540533 - 0.421691 &\approx \mathbf{0.037776}\\
\end{align}
$$
We have the answer to (a) now. The probability of accepting a lot in Phase I is $\mathbf{0.540533}$

Now for question b. First let's figure out the total possibilities of failure and accpetance in Phase II, or the proportion of the $0.421691$ gets rejected or accepted.

We have three possible entry points into Phase II: failures of 3, 4, or 5 units. If 3 fail, we can accept up to three more out of the 100, if 4 have failed in Phase I, we can only have 0, 1 or 2 fail in Phase II, and if 5 have failed, we must have no more than 1 failure. The possible probabilities are:
$$
\begin{align}
P(0) = {100 \choose 0}0.05^0 0.95^{100} &\approx 0.005921\\
P(1) = {100 \choose 1}0.05^1 0.95^{99} &\approx 0.031161\\
P(2) = {100 \choose 2}0.05^2 0.95^{98} &\approx 0.081182\\
P(3) = {100 \choose 3}0.05^3 0.95^{97} &\approx 0.139576\\
\end{align}
$$
So accepting in Phase II given 3 failures in Phase I is $P_I(3)\cdot P_{II}(0, 1, 2, 3)$ or approximately $(0.219875\cdot(0.257839) \approx 0.056692)$, accepting in Phase II given 4 failures in Phase I is $P_I(4)\cdot P_{II}(0, 1, 2)$ or approximately $(0.135975\cdot(0.118263) \approx 0.016081)$, and the probability of accepting in Phase II given 5 failures in Phase I is $P_I(5)\cdot P_{II}(0, 1)$ or approximately $(0.065841\cdot(0.037081) \approx 0.002441)$.

Question (B) asks for the conditional probability of acceptance given it has entered Phase II. This should be:
$$
P(\textrm{Accept}|\textrm{Phase II}) = \frac{P(\textrm{Accept} \cap \textrm{Phase II})}{P(\textrm{Phase II)}} \approx \frac{.075215}{.421691} \approx \mathbf{0.178364}
$$

Comment: Thank you, you are very clear